# turning the images to grayscale using jQuery with opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make my images grayscale using CSS, but it doesn't work on Firefox unless you use SVG. But the thing is when you use SVG the other functionality like opacity and transitions will do not work.

I was hoping if i can find similar code using jQuery which supports all the browsers.

Here is my CSS :

```
#myimage img{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(60%) opacity(.3);
     -moz-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(60%) opacity(.3);
      -ms-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(60%) opacity(.3);
       -o-filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(60%) opacity(.3);
        filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(60%) opacity(.3);
         filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\' filterRes=\'800\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
          filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
           filter:alpha(opacity=6);
            -moz-opacity: 0.6;
    o-transition: .7s;
    -ms-transition: .7s;
    -moz-transition: .7s;
    -webkit-transition: .7s;
    transition: .7s;





}
#myimage img:hover{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\' filterRes=\'800\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    opacity: (.5);
    o-transition: .7s;
    -ms-transition: .7s;
    -moz-transition: .7s;
    -webkit-transition: .7s;
    transition: .7s;
}
```

Has anyone done it before that could help me out with this?

Comment: A quick Google comes up with this source that reports to work across many browsers: http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

Comment: @BigChris Thanks! But if you take a look at my question again, i asked about opacity and transition support. My code is already work on every browser

Answer (score 1):

I am just including a complete example using css and jquery for fading in/out and making grayScale and vice versa for images.

the most important part for grayScaling is:

```
$('#yourImage').css({
        "filter": "grayscale(0%)",
        "-webkit-filter": "grayscale(0%)"
    });
```

This can be used in jquery whenever an image gets hover/click:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".testimonial_image").click(function(){
        // save id of div the image is clicked
        var box_id = $(this).attr("id");

        // Fade out authors images using class
        $(".testimonial_image").fadeTo(600, 0.3);

        // Grayscale authors images using class
        $('.testimonial_image').css({
            "filter": "grayscale(100%)",
            "-webkit-filter": "grayscale(100%)"
        });

        // Fade in author's images which is clicked using id
        $('#'+box_id).fadeTo(600, 1);

        // remove Grayscale from clicked author's images using id
        $('#'+box_id).css({
            "filter": "grayscale(0%)",
            "-webkit-filter": "grayscale(0%)"
        });
    });

});
```

```css
#content_1 .testimonial_image {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px !important;
    width: 178px;
    height: 178px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url('https://github.com/jawadmjn/fading-in-fading-out-and-grey-scale-on-images/blob/master/assets/images/home_testimonial_sprite.jpg?raw=true');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* START on load opacity of images is 0.3 and they are grayscale */
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    /* END on load opacity of images is 0.3 and they are grayscale */
}
#content_1 .testimonial_image:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#content_1 #testimonial1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
    filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
#content_1 #testimonial2 {
    background-position: -186px 0;
}
#content_1 #testimonial3 {
    background-position: -377px 0;
}
#content_1 #testimonial4 {
    background-position: -2px -187px;
}
#content_1 #testimonial5 {
    background-position: -199px -187px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_1">
    <div class="testimonial_image" id="testimonial1"></div>
    <div class="testimonial_image" id="testimonial2"></div>
    <div class="testimonial_image" id="testimonial3"></div>
    <div class="testimonial_image" id="testimonial4"></div>
    <div class="testimonial_image" id="testimonial5"></div>
</div>
```

A complete demo for gray scale using css and javascript: [grayScale java and css](https://github.com/jawadmjn/fading-in-fading-out-and-grey-scale-on-images)

Comment: Can you add some content from the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a canvas element to dynamically create a grayscale version of your image.

This bypasses the need to support cross-browser filters.

Then you can use normal CSS to transition between the color<->grayscale images as desired.

[image]

Example code to create a grayscale version of a color image using an html canvas element:

```
var grayImg=new Image();

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolSmall.png";
function start(){
    img2Grayscale(img,grayImg);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(grayImg);
}

function img2Grayscale(sourceImg,grayImg){
    var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width=sourceImg.width;
    canvas.height=sourceImg.height;
    ctx.drawImage(sourceImg,0,0);
    var imageData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data=imageData.data;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4){
        // make the r,g,b components of this pixel == the average of r,g,b
        data[i+0]=data[i+1]=data[i+2]=(data[i]+data[i+1]+data[i+2])/3;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
    grayImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to target bunch of images? Actually i'm using PHP to load images from database not just one image. Like this : <?php the_filed(image); ?>

Comment: Sure.  Assume you have added a class='grayMe' to each image element you wish to hover-colorize (those images are sent full-color).  On the client-side, you can `$('.grayMe').each` to run a function on all class='grayMe' images. The function calls img2Grayscale on each member of the 'grayMe' set and overlays the grayscale image on top of each color image (set color image opacity=0). Then it's normal CSS to transition from the newly created grayscale to the full-color image on hover. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'm newbie in jquery, can you come up with an jsbin example? I really appreciate it

Comment: I have confidence in you. :-)  Try doing the code yourself and ask another question if you need more help.  Cheers!